# kotlin coroutines: how to avoid multiple calls of map() if we have 2 or more collectors

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlinx.coroutines.flow

There is code sample:

```
fun main() {
    runBlocking {
        val sourceFlow = MutableSharedFlow<Int>()

        val mappedFlow = sourceFlow
            .map {
                println("INSIDE MAP")
                return@map it.toString()
            }


        launch {
            mappedFlow.collect {
                println(it)
            }
        }

        launch {
            mappedFlow.collect {
                println(it)
            }
        }

        launch {
            delay(1000)
            sourceFlow.emit(1)
        }
    }
}
```

I have one sourceFlow with mapping and 2 collectors.
this program will print:

```
INSIDE MAP
1
INSIDE MAP
1
```

In real case I have sourceFlow with some mapping from database, and it is heavy operation.
I want to avoid double-mapping for the same value.

For first attemption I created this fun:

```
suspend fun <R> Flow<R>.flatten(scope: CoroutineScope): Flow<R> {
    val flow = MutableSharedFlow<R>()
    scope.launch {
        collect {
            flow.emit(it)
        }
    }
    return flow
}
```

To use it like this:

```
val mappedFlow = sourceFlow
    .map {
        println("INSIDE MAP")
        return@map it.toString()
    }.flatten(this)
```

Does Kotlin coroutines some other way to implement it? Does anybody see any problems with offered solution?

Comment: See [shareIn()](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/share-in.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have recreated the behavior of the base library's [`shareIn`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/share-in.html) flow operator function with `started` set to `SharingStarted.Eagerly` and `replay` set to 0, and the result upcast to a generic Flow. Also, your function is needlessly marked `suspend`. Like any other flow operator, there's no reason it should need to suspend. The name "flatten" could be confusing since the behavior is nothing like the `List.flatten`, `Flow.flattenConcat`, and `Flow.flattenMerge` functions.